# Difference between vaco and vagor?

Tags: vocabulary

The verbs vaco and vagor seem to be very similar but nevertheless are obviously carefully differentiated in Latin and were not coalesced, so I suppose there is some specific difference in meaning between them which is not captured in English lexicons. What is it?

Comment: Uhm, for English speakers, it's the difference between "vacant" and "vagrant," no?

Comment: One is to be empty and the other is to wander. I really don't see the similarity.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Hmm, maybe I have made a mistake in using the dictionary. This is the entry I was relying on that says vaco means wander: https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?parola=vaco . Is this wrong?

Comment: [Yeah, that's just straight-up wrong.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=vaco)

Comment: Best to go first to [Lewis and Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?), or at least double check with it.

Comment: Could I perhaps suggest you include the dictionary entries you have used for the two words, to specify what it is that you take note of?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the online dictionary I was using has a more or less incorrect definition of vaco and did not include the most common understanding of the word which is to be vacant or empty.